# How to use pycharm to auto indent the select area by the template of the coding style

Tags: pycharm

Well, In eclipse, I can set the code-style template , when the code finish, I could indent it by the template.
For example,

In the coding style template, I set the style is as following:

`aDict = {1: 'a', 2: 'b'}`  ## that is each variable got a whitespace in front of it

If I write the code like this

```
aDict = {1:'a',2:      'b'}
```

How can I indent the code after I wrote it?

I tried the "code-Auto Indent Lines", which is binding to Hot-Key "Ctrl + Alt + I",but It seems doesn't work

Answer (score 39, accepted):

That action is called `Reformat code`. You can find it in `Code` menu, somewhere in the middle, or use the hotkey <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: How do you disable the `Auto-Indent Lines` when you `Reformat Code`? It seems to run every time now, where before I could set it as a separate in a dialog.

Comment: If you don't know the shortcut don't post

Comment: `Alt+Cmd+L` by default on the latest PyCharm

Answer (score 29):

The latest version of PyCharm uses <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>  + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> in both Linux and Windows. Then from the reformat dialog box, choose what reformatting option you want to perform.

Answer (score 9):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> will reformat your code.

Comment: On Windows it's [Ctrl] + [Alt] + [L]

Comment: it is ctrl + shift + alt + L

Answer (score 9):

If you happen to use/switch to Mac then the default is is cmd+alt+L

Answer (score 5):

On Mac OS you can use `Option` + `Command` + `L` to reformat/auto-indent the selected area of code. I am using the version 2021.1.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows 10, keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>

The option can be found in Code menu -> Auto-Indent Lines

Comment: it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

As of PyCharm 2020.3.3 the settings for reformatting a specific part of code should be:
`CTRL` + `ALT` + `L`

For the whole file:
`CTRL` + `ALT` + `SHIFT` + `L`

[PyCharm Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nZUA.png)

I recommend using pre-commit hook when pushing to origin as with pre-commit u can use black hooks to reformat your file to standard coding appearances

Answer (score 0):

Another shortcut for the latest version 2017.2.3 is: <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd>

To view other option go to `Code` menu above.

Answer (score 0):

For macOs Go to

1. `Code` > `Reformate code`

or

2.`Option` + `Command` + `L`

Reference Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2Wa6.png